# NSMutableDictionary does not work properly

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

Currently I have a very strange problem using NSMutableDictionary: same code, same data but different results of key-value pairs objects.

My dictionary uses an user-defined class objects as keys and values are array of objects.

Here is the code to build dictionary:

```
_designs = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (Hierarchy * hier in downloadedHierarchies.objects)
{
    NSLog(@"Hierarchy [%d - %d - %@]", hier.designId, hier.hierarchyId, hier.hierarchyName);
    Design * aDesign = [[Design alloc] initWithId:hier.designId withName:hier.designName];

    NSMutableArray *array = ([_designs objectForKey:aDesign] == nil) ? [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] : (NSMutableArray *)[_designs objectForKey:aDesign];
    NSLog(@"Design %d has %d of hierarchies", aDesign.designId, array.count);

    [array addObject:hier];

    [_designs setObject:array forKey:aDesign];
    NSLog(@"Design %d now has %d of hierarchies", aDesign.designId, [[_designs objectForKey:aDesign] count]);
}
```

Problem is:
   - My test data  has only 1 design and 3 hierarchies. Each time I run the application, I get different results in my dictionary. Sometimes I get 2 key-value pairs, sometimes 3. Even keys are from the same design (same designId), and hierarchies are scattered among those key-value pairs.

Some notes:

- Design has already implemented NSCopying as well as isEqual and tested ok
- Hierarchy has also implemented NSCopying
- Debug these lines of code give correct results

What have I done wrong here ?

Comment: in `[_designs setObject:array forKey:aDesign];` key should be a string not an object.

Comment: hi samfisher, according to Apple, key can be an object conforming to NSCopying protocol. So I believe it's not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also provide isEqual and hash in your Design object. This is taken from NSObject's Protocol description:

isEqual:
Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver and a given object are equal. (required)

- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)anObject
  Parameters
  anObject
  The object to be compared to the receiver.
  Return Value
  YES if the receiver and anObject are equal, otherwise NO.

Discussion
This method defines what it means for instances to be equal. For example, a container object might define two containers as equal if their corresponding objects all respond YES to an isEqual: request. See the NSData, NSDictionary, NSArray, and NSString class specifications for examples of the use of this method.

If two objects are equal, they must have the same hash value. This last point is particularly important if you define isEqual: in a subclass and intend to put instances of that subclass into a collection. Make sure you also define hash in your subclass.

Comment: You're the man, David :). Adding hash method solves it. However I decided not implement hash method since the beginning because I thought by default it should returns the same value, hence implement isEqual is enough.